# Remap the §± key on my magic keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have been provided with a Magic Keyboard with my new work kit and I'm not sure it is a default Australian keyboard.

Above the 3 is £ not # (although shift + press does use #) so the pound symbol is not used without control+press but it's there.

The big issue is that to the left of 1, there is no tilde/backtick (~/`) key. The tilde key is actually down to the right of the left shift key. In the typical tilde key position is ±/§ which is entirely useless to me. Considering how often I spend in terminals, the tilde key is very important to me and I have hit this § key a thousand times in the past 3 days.

Is there a way to remap this key? I tried Karabiner with no luck.

Note that the keyboard is in the prefs as an Australian keyboard.

This image is not the same as mine, I dont have the extra characters but it does show the location of the keys I am referring to. (Ignore the red highlights, that wasnt me).

[image]

Comment: BTW, the keyboard layout you're describing is UK English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keyboard is no doubt the one called English - Great Britain in the [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794).

One common way to do what you want is to create a custom keyboard layout via the [Ukelele app](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).

Comment: I am using the Great British input source now and theres no change. That key continues to work as §/± even though the keyboard image in Inputs shows it as `/~ - Ukelele didn't recognise the keypress on the §± key.

Comment: @Christian The British input source is not supposed to work the way you want.  Email me and I will send you a new layout   Tom at bluesky dot org

Answer (score 2):

This will require your participation :)

1. Download and run free [Key Codes](https://manytricks.com/keycodes/) utility.
2. Press <kbd>± §</kbd> key on your keyboard and write its HEX code from the utility screen.
3. Press <kbd>` _</kbd> key and write HEX code for it.
4. Open Terminal app and enter the following command (copy and paste it):

   hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000**32**,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x7000000**35**},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000**35**,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x7000000**32**}]}'

   `HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc` is what you press on your keyboard and `HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey` is what will be the result.
5. Pay attention to the bolded numbers endings!! You will need to replace them with actual readings from the Key Codes utility (Step 2 and 3). I wrote most probable values, but they may differ in your case.

As an alternative solution, you may want to try [Flamingo](https://openfibers.github.io/flamingo/) app.

Reference to the **hidutil** usage is here: [Technical Note TN2450](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2450/_index.html).

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work. The codes were 10 and 50 and while the command gave no errors, there was no change in keyboard behaviour. Flamingo didn't work either. Its worth noting that my keypress on that ± key desn't have any effect in some apps.

Comment: So I had this same problem and got it to work with the hex code 0x700000039 using hidutil. (The Key Codes utility doesn't display the 'keyboard' hex codes.)

Comment: @ChrisO'Sullivan how did you get the keyboard hex code from the key code?

Comment: hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000064,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000035}]}'

Worked for me.
Source: https://dchakarov.com/blog/macbook-remap-keys/

Comment: `0x32` and `0x35` are the keycodes for US keyboards. The Australian keyboard has the same layout as a US one, therefore, the keycodes are the same. By asking the OP to download a software to generate keycodes (wrong ones), it makes the answer wrong and more confusing. I suggest you remove steps 1, 2, 3 and 5.